# Delete record when update record in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

- `UserActivationCode` UA
- `User` U

When use send the enter the activation code, I need to check the code in `UA`; if it exists, go to `User` and update column `IsActive = true` and when `IsActive` is  true, go back to `UserActivationCode` and delete record of `UserCode`.

I wrote this code :

```
UPDATE [User] 
SET IsActive = 1 
FROM [User] U 
JOIN [UserActivationCode] UA ON U.Email = UA.Username 
WHERE UA.Username = @Username 
  AND UA.ActivationCode=  @ActivationCode 
  AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() 
  AND U.IsActive = 0
```

but what should I change my code for back and delete record in `UserActivationCode`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Merge [statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) here

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Username VARCHAR(100));

MERGE [User] AS U
USING [UserActivetionCode] AS UA 
ON (U.Email = UA.Username AND UA.Username = @Username AND UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() AND U.IsActive = 0) 
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE SET U.IsActive = 1 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND 1 < 0
   THEN DELETE UA.Username INTO @T;


DELETE FROM [UserActivetionCode] WHERE UA.Username NOT IN(SELECT Username FROM @T)
```

Comment: i need when success delete the record of `UserActivetionUser`

Answer (score 1):

you can add `IF EXISTS` condition you on your TSQL.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [User] t1
    JOIN [UserActivetionCode] t2 t1.Email = t2.Username 
    WHERE  UA.Username = @Username AND UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode 
        AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() AND U.IsActive = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [User] SET IsActive=1 FROM [User] U JOIN [UserActivetionCode] UA ON 
    U.Email=UA.Username WHERE UA.Username = @Username AND UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode 
    AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() AND U.IsActive = 0

    DELETE FROM [UserActivetionCode] WHERE  UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode 
END
```

Comment: why use twice this condation ?? `UA.Username = @Username AND UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode 
        AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() AND U.IsActive = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserActivationCode UA JOIN User U 
    ON UA.Username = U.Email
    WHERE UA.Username = @Username
    AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() 
    AND U.IsActive = 0)
THEN
    UPDATE [User] 
    SET IsActive = 1 
    FROM [User] U JOIN [UserActivationCode] UA ON U.Email = UA.Username 
    WHERE UA.Username = @Username 
      AND UA.ActivationCode=  @ActivationCode 
      AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() 
      AND U.IsActive = 

ELSE
    DELETE FROM [UserActivetionCode] WHERE  UA.ActivetionCode=  @ActivetionCode
```

Comment: A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_ is not a [control-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-ver15) _statement_.

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes some assumptions since you didn't provide DDL for your tables. It wraps the work in a transaction to make the operation atomic (assuming a suitable transaction isolation level).

```
begin transaction;

declare @UserCodes as Table ( UserCode Int );

UPDATE [User] 
SET IsActive = 1 
-- Capture the   UserCode   of any affected rows.
output inserted.UserCode into @UserCodes
FROM [User] U 
JOIN [UserActivationCode] UA ON U.Email = UA.Username 
WHERE UA.Username = @Username 
  AND UA.ActivationCode = @ActivationCode 
  AND UA.ExpireTime < GETDATE() 
  AND U.IsActive = 0;

-- If any rows were updated then delete the corresponding   UserActivationCode   row(s).
delete from UserActivationCode 
  where UserCode in ( select UserCode from @UserCodes );

commit transaction;
```